# In VMware Infrastructure client does deleting a previous snapshot affect any current snapshot?

Tags: snapshot, vmware-vcenter

In the VMware Infrastructure client, does deleting a previous snapshot affect any current snapshot? Assuming I am saving the memory state.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Deleting a snapshot collapses out the disk differential for just that snapshot, as well as removing its memory snapshot if it exists.

Assuming that you don't accidentally hit the 'delete all' button, the removal of any given snapshot does not affect any other snapshot.